# Instantiate an unknown at compile time child of an abstract class

Tags: c#

**EDIT**

See Amir Popovich's solution for answer and a follow up question (how to pass CTOR params)

Here's the inner loop of my final code:

```
//The names of my children classes are the gpib name from *?IDN
//Some start with numbers, thus removing the _ character
if (child.Name.Replace("_","") == gpibInstrument)
{
    var instance = (GpibDevice)Activator.CreateInstance(child, gpibAddr);
    gpibDeviceList.add(instance);
    break;
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

I'm trying to figure out how to instantiate an unknown at compile time child class of an abstract class based on some set of logic. The logic is as follows:

1. Get connected equipment
2. Instantiate classes based off of the equipment I see
3. Return a list of those classes

The main reason I'm doing this is so I don't have to come back to this code and add the different child classes as I add more child classes.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
//Get IEnumerable of available children class types of my abstract
//class GpibDevice
var children = typeof(GpibDevice)
               .Assembly.GetTypes()
               .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(GpibDevice)) && !t.IsAbstract);

//Get list of connected equipment
string[] equipList = GpibUtilites.GetEquipmentNames();

//List which will contain the newly instantiated classes
List<GpibDevice> gpibDeviceList = new List<GpibDevice>();

foreach (var gpibInstrument in equipList)
{
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        if(child.Identifier == gpibInstrument)
        {
            //////INSTATIATE HERE//////
            gpibDeviceList.add(instantiatedClass);
        }
    }
}
return gpibDeviceList;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should use a factory/builder approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) and cast to your abstract class:

```
if(child.Identifier == gpibInstrument)
{
    //////INSTATIATE HERE//////
    var instance = (AbstractClassType)Activator.CreateInstance(child);
    gpibDeviceList.add(instantiatedClass);
}
```

If you know you class has parameters in it's CTOR, you can pass then as an object[]:

```
var @params = new object[]{p1,p2...pn};
var instance = (AbstractClassType)Activator.CreateInstance(child, @params);
```

Comment: Please note that `params` is a keyword. I've edited your answer to make it compilable.